# Node Kakfa receiving BrokerNotAvailable errors

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to get started with NodeJS and Kafka. I have one Kafka server running in a docker container with one Zookeeper server.

I can successfully connect a listener to my topic and when my code behaves I see messages passed from Producer to Consumer.

However - more often than not, my code fails with an error. Here are two consecutive attempts to Produce a message into the Kafka topic

```
2018-01-09T22:14:29.061Z - info: KafkaProducer: client is ready
err: null
data: [object Object]


err: BrokerNotAvailableError: Broker not available
data: undefined
2018-01-09T22:15:03.770Z - info: KafkaProducer: client is ready
```

The code that I'm using to publish the message is here:

```
'use strict';

const log = require('./Logger');
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const Producer = kafka.Producer;
const KeyedMessage = kafka.KeyedMessage;
const Client = kafka.Client;
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const uuid = require('uuid');

const client = new Client('192.168.99.100:2181', 'test', {
  sessionTimeout: 300,
  spinDelay: 100,
  retries: 2
});
const producer = new Producer(client, {requireAcks: 1});

producer.on('ready', () => {
  log.info('KafkaProducer: client is ready');
});

producer.on('error', (err) => {
  log.error(`KafkaProducer: ${err}`);
});

class KafkaProducer {

  constructor() {}

  sendRecord(type, userId, sessionId, data, callback) {

    if (!userId) {
      return callback(new Error('A userId must be provided.'));
    }

    const event = {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      userId: userId,
      sessionId: sessionId,
      type: type,
      data: data
    };

    const buffer = new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(event));

    // Create a new payload
    const record = [
      {
        topic: 'datastore',
        messages: buffer,
        attributes: 1 /* Use GZip compression for the payload */
      }
    ];

    //Send record to Kafka and log result/error
    producer.send(record, callback);

  }
}

module.exports = KafkaProducer;
```

Not particularly elegant code, but I'm just trying to get a simple use case working before integrating Kafka into my application.

If it is relevant this are my Dockerfiles for Kafka and Zookeeper

```
FROM wurstmeister/kafka:1.0.0

ENV KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME service-kafka
ENV KAFKA_PORT 9092
ENV KAFKA_HOST_NAME service-kafka
ENV KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT service-zookeeper:2181
ENV KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS "auth:1:1,datastore:1:1,transactions:1:1"
```

and

```
FROM zookeeper:latest
```

[This comment in a GitHub issue](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/297#issuecomment-249324232) seems to suggest that it is the applications responsibility to catch connection errors and retry the message, but this happens so frequently there is something else wrong that I need some guidance with. Thanks

Comment: The answer was obvious having slept on it. I introduced a race condition where often the producer wasn't ready before sending the message. Putting the send method inside the listener for the producer 'ready' event fixed it

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I made the same mistake. Maybe you could answer your own question and set it as solution. Would help future readers :).